# Patching imported open from imported file with mock

Tags: python, mocking

I have two files:

```
#file1.py
def_writefile():
    ...
    fp = open('file')
    fp.write('blah')
    ...


#file2.py
file1.writefile()
```

I've tried patching open different ways:

```
#test_file.py
fn = mock.mock_open()
with mock.patch('__builtin__.open', fn):
    file1.writefile()

with mock.patch('file1.open', fn):
    file1.writefile()

with mock.patch('file2.open', fn):
    file1.writefile()

with mock.patch('__main__.open', fn, create=True):
    file1.writefile()

assert(mock_file().write.called_once_with('blah'))
```

But none of them seem to work. What is the correct way to patch a builtin like open from an imported module using mock?

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
import file1

fn = mock.mock_open()
with mock.patch('file1.open', fn, create=True):
    file1.writefile()

fn().write.assert_called_once_with('blah')
```

You need to mock the `open` function that will be used in `file1.py`, so we pass `'file1.open'` isntead of `'__main__.open'`. The other piece you were missing is that you weren't using the right function to make sure `write` was called with the correct parameters - you need to use the [`assert_called_once_with`](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html?highlight=assert_called_once#mock.Mock.assert_called_once_with) function that's built into the `Mock` class.

`create=True` is required because the `open` function won't be found in the `file1` class at import time, because the `open` function won't actually be pulled into the module until runtime. Normally that means `mock` will thrown an exception saying `file1` is missing the attribute. Adding `create=True` makes `mock` create the attribute when it doesn't find it, and is [mentioned in the docs](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html?highlight=create#mock.patch) as being useful for this situation:

> This is useful for writing tests against attributes that your
>   production code creates at runtime